# Undo and Redo Button title and actions with NSUndomanager

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad-2

I am creating  an ios application like sudoku.In that application i  created undo redo buttons.In sudoku each grid values are button titles.What i want is whenever i click  undo or redo buttons then the grid values changed depending on the actions.can i do with it NSUndomanager?is  there any sample code..?give me solution

```
  if([value intValue] == 0)
            {
                CurrentTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[b titleLabel ]text]];
                    [self AllSweepFunctionAction];
                    [b setTitle:appendedString forState:0];


                if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
                {
                    [[b titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kids" size:15]];
                }else
                {
                    [[b titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kids" size:7]];
                }
                [b setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:0];
                [ b titleLabel].lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
                [b titleLabel].textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            }
```

Comment: Show some code. What approach you have done?

Answer (score 0):

First the ViewControllers will need to be able to become the first responder to handle gestures, so write this method in your ViewController

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Secondly: The view controller will need to become the first responder when it appears onscreen, 
This can be done by calling `[self becomeFirstResponder]` in `-loadView` or `-viewDidLoad`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

You can experiment with the delay time

Then You can register for property changes in your viewController, and call the `undo` method of the `NSUndoManager` in your button action. 
Also I think you can override this view's controller method for editing purpose

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
//do some editing 


}
```

**Here is the sample code, containing undo code**

Here's [a link](https://github.com/darcyliu/SampleCode/tree/master/SimpleUndo)!

In the code Link above add this code to viewDidLoad of the  RootViewController.m

```
 // left undo button
    UIBarButtonItem *undoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(undoOperations:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = undoButton;
```

And somewhere in the this `RootViewController.m` add this method

```
-(void)undoOperations:(id)sender
{
    [self.undoManager undo];

}
```

You should have a left button with undo's, I think this gives a good start.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.